# Хранение данных на сервере

Tags: база-данных, ios, swift

Здрастье. Делаю приложеньку идей. Концепция такова:
 -Пользователь читает/пишет идеи.
Но как и где хранить эти идеи?
Я просто новичок. (Платформа iOS)

Comment: Распишите подробнее свое видение. Для чего Вы хотите хранить это на сервере, чем не устраивает локально? Хотите хранить где-то централизованно?

Comment: Я просто не понимаю. Как сделать так чтобы люди смогли видеть идеи?

Comment: Всмысле как? как запрограммируете так и будет.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется для первого опыта работы с бекендом идеально подойдет [firebase google](https://firebase.google.com). Сейчас есть очень много гайдов по его изучению. Попробуйте этот сервис.